# Issue with android gradle plugin version 3.3 and OneSignal

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, repository, build.gradle, onesignal

When I updated, `Gradle 4.6 -> 4.10.1` and the `Android Gradle plugin 3.2.1 -> 3.3.1`, I get the following errors:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0, 27.2.0).
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0, 27.2.0).
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app

While inspecting dependancies I found OneSignal `implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'` was throwing above errors for ex.

```sh
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
```

Now coming to `https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk` is used to fetch the dependencies required for [JustPay integration](https://juspay.in/docs/advanced/ec/android_integration/index.html).

**Problem**
Why wrong repository is used when resolving above dependancies for compiling the project? Am I doing something wrong or something has changed in gradle 3.3 which is causing this? Or its an issue of gradle 3.3.1?

*Solution* : Excluding this libs does solves the problem.

```sh
implementation ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6') {
     exclude group : 'com.google.android.gms'
     exclude group : 'com.android.support'
     exclude group : 'com.google.firebase'
}
```

I am not sure, It may have adverse affects though(If any please do let me know). But I want to get to the root of the problem I want to know why this is only happening for Android Gradle plugin 3.3.1 and the same works just fine with Android Gradle plugin 3.2.1 `i.e. without excluding this dependancies`.

Here is my app/build.gradle file

```sh
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$rootProject.fabricGradle"
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/'
    }
}

android {
....
....
}

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'
...
}
```

build.gradle file

```sh
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
...
}
```

**Update** : I know it has something to do with Improved classpath synchronization which is introduced in 3.3, but still have no clue why is it trying to resolve those dependencies with wrong repository.

**Update 2**
I have tried following as well

```sh
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]' //as well ) at the end
}
```

Comment: I faced same issue like you

Comment: - Possible solution: Can you please first check that internet is working fine on your system and then next your Gradle in Settings has not ticked the checkbox "Work Offline".

Comment: - If above both are good then just make any little change in Module:app gradle file and Sync again. It'll download all required files and then you'll be ready to work again.

Comment: @Harpreet Both are good and the problem is while resolving transitive dependancies of OneSignal gradle is using wrong repository.

Comment: @SuyashChavan Can you please follow exact the documentation once. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: No luck, still the problem is same

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem from command line with the build gradle files you provided.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Mpm03MB Its still a problem for me. Can you please post the app and project build.gradle here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:
Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle ->`

And `uncheck` "Offline work" option.

**Update:**

Remove below line of code

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

from top-level `build.gradle` file sync and check it once.

Comment: I have mentioned this exact solution in the question itself. Please do read the issue :/

Comment: It's unchecked.